# UIPikcerView Multiple selection values swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, multipleselection

I'm using UIPickerView in button the only problem which I've faced I want user can select the multiple values from UIPickerView not only one values and also change background colour accordingly when user select multiple item.See my code and pic you get an idea what trying to achieve thanks.

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonRole: UIButton!    
    var rolesPicker = UIPickerView()
    var toolBar = UIToolbar()
    var userRoles:\[String\] = \["Importer","Creater","Writer","Barber"\]
    var selectedIndex :Int = 0
    
    @IBAction func didTapPickRoles(_ sender: UIButton) {
        rolesPicker = UIPickerView.init()
        rolesPicker.delegate = self
        rolesPicker.dataSource = self
        rolesPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        rolesPicker.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        rolesPicker.contentMode = .center
        rolesPicker.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
           self.view.addSubview(rolesPicker)
        toolBar = UIToolbar.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50))
        toolBar.items = \[UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onDoneButtonTapped))\]
           self.view.addSubview(toolBar)
        rolesPicker.selectRow(selectedIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        buttonRole.layer.borderWidth = 1
        buttonRole.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

    }
    
    @objc func onDoneButtonTapped() {
        toolBar.removeFromSuperview()
        rolesPicker.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
extension PickerViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return userRoles.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        userRoles\[row\]
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedIndex = row
        buttonRole.setTitle(userRoles\[row\], for: .normal)
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You Can try with this Cocoapods pleas check this https://github.com/aselivanov/UIMultiPicker